# How can I adjust my text to my screen sizes, and fix position

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

How can I adjust my text to my screen sizes, and fix position.

I want my text be in a middle and adjust my positions to fix it

I did the right think to get text in a middle or have another better way?
and how can I fix my issue with position.

Thank for help !

my HTML

```
<div class="text-center">

    <h2>Protein for healthy muscle and bone</h2>

    <strong>proteins in the diet contribute significantly to the production of energy for the body.</strong>

</div>
```

my css - bootstrap 4 + that component

```
h2, h4, p, strong, small {
    color: oldlace;
}

div {
    position: absolute;
    top: 10%;
    margin-left: 25%;
    width: 700px;
}
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed `width: 700px` to `min-width: 700px` and added `width: 50%` property to `div`, let me know that do you think about this solution:

```css
body {
    background: black;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

h2, h4, p, strong, small {
    color: oldlace;
}

div {
    position: relative;
    top: 10%;
    min-width: 700px;
    width: 50%;
    text-align: center;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="text-center">

    <h2>Protein for healthy muscle and bone</h2>

    <strong>proteins in the diet contribute significantly to the production of energy for the body.</strong>

</div>
```

Notice that I also changed the `margin` property to `text-align: center`, it's a cleaner solution if you don't need particular CSS.

- Edit: I added these properties for `body` and `div`: `margin-left: auto;` and `margin-right: auto;`

Now it's working

Comment: Still have the same problem when I resize my screen to smaller. edit - I see this element in a middle but with same issue

Comment: in xl and l screen size is work well but in m and s sizes isn't work and cut the right text. moreover don't have some spacing right and left anymore in that sizes

Comment: The only thing left to edit is the `min-width` property that at the moment has `700px` as value, try to set it to `auto`

Comment: But i want that size for text show how can i use that size and fix it?

Comment: Well, what do you think about the result you can achieve editing `div` class by removing `min-width` property and setting `width: 100%;`?

Comment: width: 70% work perfectly but , This is the right way to do it? and why need min-width: 700px if it doing always problems?

Comment: It's the right way: `width` with a percentage value allows you to force the screen size to be responsive. About `min-width: 700px`, it sets the lowest value available, the users need it if they have to set a minimal size, under that the window has not the possibility to force downsize